# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbar' Django 3.1

Tags: python, django, module, pip

I'm facing a "common" problem apparently as I searched and found several topics about it. None of the answer provided worked for me as I already did everything mentionned.

1. I setup the virtualenv
2. Then, I installed django-degub-toolbar

   `pip install django-debug-toolbar`
3. Add the application in the settings

   ```py
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
       # External apps
       'debug_toolbar',
       # Internal apps
       ...,
   ]
   ```
4. And edited the middleware

   ```py
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
       'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
       # Django Toolbar interaction with the middleware
       'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
   ]
   ```

But nothing worked and I still got the error when I run the server.

Traceback

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saiko-san/Documents/app-mangas-collection/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 45, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/Users/saiko-san/Documents/app-mangas-collection/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/saiko-san/Documents/app-mangas-collection/mangas_collection/mangas_collection/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/Users/saiko-san/Documents/app-mangas-collection/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/Users/saiko-san/Documents/app-mangas-collection/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/saiko-san/Documents/app-mangas-collection/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/Users/saiko-san/Documents/app-mangas-collection/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbar'
```

Comment: Full traceback please.

Comment: Put `DebugToolbarMiddleware` just below `CommonMiddleware`

Comment: If still fails, try the second option in this link https://gist.github.com/douglasmiranda/9de51aaba14543851ca3

Comment: @user70 Why? It's not about showing, it's an import error, his runserver won't even start. And it has nothing to do with ordering. Most likely he didn't activate his virtualenv before installing, but it will show from traceback.

Comment: @Melvyn Yes, we need the traceback, thank you

Comment: Thanks for your support. For a reason, I can't explain, it's working now.

Like I said in my explanation above, I activate the virtualenv before installing, which is why I couldn't explain why this error occured. I run the server with python binary from my virtualenv's bin folder. I know it doesn't change anything but still...

I will still post my traceback if it can help someone else

Comment: @aliitaqk can you check the commas in the INSTALLED_APPS and inform me? By the way, put your traceback to your original question.

Comment: Yes, the comma was not missing, you can see it above :)

Comment: This would happen if you have runserver already running, change your settings while debug toolbar is being installed. runserver sees the settings change, will reload the server, but the module isn't there yet. It won't recover by itself, until you change code that it's watching (so code in your repo, not 3rd-party). If that's not the case, write it up as a glitch, caused by some OS-level filesystem caching and move on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into an error with multiple python executables. Add this line to your code to check which executable it is using:

```
import sys
print(f"Using this python executable: {sys.executable}")
```

Let's say it outputs `/some/path/bin/python3`. Then install `django-debug-toolbar` for that executable:

```
/some/path/bin/python3 -m pip install django-debug-toolbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you activate your virtual environment.?
if not please activate first with the command pipenv shell

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).